# Generalized eigenfunctions of the normal operator and resolution of identity

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Consider a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}\simeq L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\otimes V$ where $V\simeq \mathbb{C}^m$ is a finite-dimensional Hilbert space and an unbounded normal operator $\hat{L}$ densely defined on $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that we are able to find the general solution of the equation
\begin{equation}
\hat{L}\psi_\lambda(x,n)=\lambda \psi_\lambda(x,n),\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}^N,\quad n=1,\cdots,m
\end{equation}
for $\lambda\in D\subset \mathbb{C}$ and able to show that the equation has no solution for $\lambda\not\in D$. For all $\lambda\in D$, $\psi_\lambda\not\in\mathcal{H}$ but they are tempered distributions. Suppose that we are also able to show that $\psi_\lambda$ are normalized in the sense of delta function:
\begin{equation}
\langle \psi_\lambda\mid\psi_{\lambda'}\rangle=\delta(\lambda,\lambda').
\end{equation}
where $\delta(\lambda,\lambda')$ is the delta function on $D$. Based on the above assumptions, can one conclude the following resolution of identity (with certain measure $d\lambda$) on $\mathcal{H}$?
\begin{equation}
\int_D d\lambda \mid \psi_\lambda\rangle\langle \psi_{\lambda}\mid=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathcal{H}}
\end{equation}

Comment: No, while being orthonormal, those eigenfunctions may not form a complete basis or even exist, even in the case of a self-adjoint operator. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557341/do-eigenvectors-of-an-unbounded-operator-form-a-complete-basis

Comment: I have assumed all eigenfunctions are tempered distributions, they do not belong to the Hilbert spaces.